# Determine the time complexity for recursive function (Big O notation)

Tags: recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I need the help to determine the time complexity for the recursive function. I know how to solve the simple cases, but i am still trying to learn how to solve the harder cases. This is only the few examples that i couldnot figure out. Any help would be much appreciated and would greatly help in my studies, Thank you!

```
int minPalindrome(string text){
    int left = 0;
    int right = text.size()-1;
    if(text=="")
        return 0;
    else if(isPalindrome(text,left,right))
        return 1;
    else{
        int minimum = text.size();
        for(int i=1;i<text.size();i++){
            minimum = min(minPalindrome(text.substr(0,i)) + minPalindrome(text.substr(i,text.size()-i)),minimum);
        }
    return minimum;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've asked for "help", but I see no attempt on your part to solve this.  Please describe in detail what you've managed to figure out, where you're stuck, etc.

Answer (score 0):

## METHOD 1

Let n denote length of string and T(n) time for length.

Clearly the operations-

```
int left = 0;
    int right = text.size()-1;
    if(text=="")
        return 0;
    else if(isPalindrome(text,left,right))
        return 1;
    else{
        int minimum = text.size();
```

occur in **constant time**(assuming equal to 1 for ease).

Then the loop takes time `2*T(n-i)` for different i, the constant `2` is multiplied because of two function calls will be done for any particular length as

length of `text.substr(0,i)` is equal to length of`text.substr(i,text.size()-i)` for some other i.

**Example(important if u dont get above para)-**

If there is three letter string "abc"

It will be divided into

```
"a" and "bc" for   i=1 
"ab" and "c" for   i=2
```

so will have **2 function calls** with both string length two("bc" and "ab") and  one("a" and "c").

Now the above results can be used to deduce-

```
   T(1)=1                   //constant time is taken when string is of one letter
   T(2)=1+2*T(1)            //it will be broken into two strings of length 1 which are used in function
   T(3)=1 + 2*T(2) + 2*T(1)     //it is broken as shown in example
       =1 + 2*(1 + 2*T(1)) + 2*T(1)
       =3  +  6*T(1)
```

Similarly, we get

```
 T(n)=1 + 2*T(n-1) + 2*T(n-2) + .......
        =1 + (2 + 4*T(n-2) + 4*T(n-3)+....) + 2*T(n-2) + 2*T(n-3)..... //expanding T(n-1)
        =3 + 6*T(n-2) +6*T(n-3) +......
        =3 +(6 + 12*T(n-3)+....) +6*T(n-3) +....
        =9 + 18*T(n-3)+..... 
        =3^2 +(3^3-3^2)*T(n-3)+....
```

For general k, we get

```
   T(n)=3^(k-1) + (3^k-3^(k-1))*T(n-k) +....
   T(n)=3^((n-1)-1) + (3^(n-1) -3^((n-1)-1))*T(n-(n-1) //for k=n-1
       =3^(n-2) + (3^(n-1)-3^(n-2))*T(1)
       =3^(n-1)  //As T(1)=1
```

which is required time complexity.

---

---

### METHOD 2

An **easiler way** to find complexity of funtion is to declare an integer with initial value zero and increment it with each function call. Then finally compare the value of this integer with value of n to get `time complexity`. It usually helps finding time complexity easily for most funtions.

YOu can declare the integer globally(which is not good practice but should work for u as we only need to find time complexity) and increment it everytime.

```
int minPalindrome(string text){

    count++;      //count is global

    int left = 0;
    int right = text.size()-1;
    if(text=="")
        return 0;
    else if(isPalindrome(text,left,right))
        return 1;
    else{
        int minimum = text.size();
        for(int i=1;i<text.size();i++){
            minimum = min(minPalindrome(text.substr(0,i)) + minPalindrome(text.substr(i,text.size()-i)),minimum);
        }
    return minimum;
    }
}
```

The result was-

```
n            count
1              1
2              3
3              9
4              27
5              81
```

From which time complexity is easily calculated to be 3^(n-1)